# Как получить доступ к компоненту другого объекта в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть пустой объект на котором висит скрипт , который должен двигать другой объект.
Раньше я двигал его с помощью :

```
Player.transform.Translate(0,20, 0);
```

Но теперь мне это нужно сделать через

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 20f));
```

Как мне это реализовать ?

Был бы рад получить объяснение на пальцах или ссылку на гайд по этому(только не мануалы юнити).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте публичное поле, и оно появится в инспекторе у объекта на котором висит скрипт.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody traget;

    void ExampleMethod(){
        traget.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 20f));
    }
}
```

Инициализируйте это поле перетаскиванием туда необходимого объекта в инспекторе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И далее в скрипте обращайтесь уже к этому полю.